# OpenGL Mapped Memory Shader Source

Tags: opengl, shaders, loading, memory-efficiency

Is there any way to get a pointer to a newly created shader object's source? I'd like to load a shader directly from file in to my shader object instead of loading to an intermediary variable and then using glShaderSource().

I haven't been able to find any information regarding this, only regarding buffers.

Answer (score -1):

Oops, this was a misunderstanding of memory mapping on my part. I should be able to grab a pointer to the file data and pass it in directly as a parameter to glShaderSource.